# React useMemo memory clean

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How i can do memory cleaning by `cat.destroy()` method when component is dead?

```
const object = useMemo(() => {
  return new Cat()
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clean up effects for hooks you execute when a component will be unmounted. It's performed by a returned function at your `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // return a function to be executed at component unmount
  return () => object.destroy()
}, [object])
```

**Note**: as @Guillaume Racicot pointed out, in some cases it's possible the object not being created yet by the time unmount is executed, hence you would face an error. In this case remember to conditionally executing `destroy`, you could use optional chaining `object?.destroy()` for that.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question. The question was: how to clean up something while using memoization

Comment: @chpio your comment doesn't make much sense. to execute a clean up effect on dismount (dead component like OP asked) you should return a function with the proper expected action (cat.destroy() in this case). the fact that the object is memoized or not is irrelevant

Comment: This won't work in react 18

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot why is that? useEffect signature didn't change in React 18.

Comment: @buzatto effects are run twice on mount in react 18, so this destroy will be called on mount before the second effect run.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot effects don't run twice in react 18, the React.StrictMode functionality forces that. React.StrictMode works only in development environment and not in production. And its usage is also optional. I suggest you to read more about in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Comment: @buzatto Strict mode does that only because it would cause bugs when an effect is misbehaving. So the strict mode actually flag this effect as being broken by calling `object.destroy()` on the first render.

Comment: that sounds reasonable, I just edited it.

Comment: `useEffect` has quite a [different lifecycle](https://react.dev/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects#the-lifecycle-of-an-effect) to `useMemo` or `useRef`. Let's quote the React [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#my-cleanup-logic-runs-even-though-my-component-didnt-unmount): "Your cleanup logic should be “symmetrical” to the setup logic ... **If you have cleanup code without corresponding setup code, it’s usually a code smell"**. This answer falls right into the trap.

Comment: I think what @gdlmx is getting at above is that `useMemo` is intended for caching purposes only. It's mentioned in the [caveats section](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#caveats) of the docs. React could, e.g., throw away the cached value for various reasons in the future. This could mean you could get two `new Cat()` calls with only one cleanup call from a `useEffect` cleanup function. Guaranteeing equal cleanups to memo calls would require more complexity.

Answer (score 4):

So, I literally thought *for sure* @buzatto's answer was correct. But having read the discussion, I tried some tests myself, and see the major difference.

It's been a couple years, so it's possible @buzatto's answer may have worked better then, but as of 2023, **do not use @buzatto's answer. In certain scenarios it will clean up right after setting up. Read below to understand why.**

1. If you're here to understand the difference, follow below.
2. TL;DR: If you're here because you want ACTUALLY working useMemo cleanup, jump to the bottom.

### Lifecycle comparison: useMemo vs. useEffect

If you render the following component in React StrictMode:

```
function Test() {
    const id = useId();

    const data = useMemo(() => {
        console.log('memo for ' + id);
        return null;
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('effect for ' + id);

        return () => {
            console.log('effect clean up ' + id);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>Test</div>
    )
}
```

You may *expect* to get these results:

```
// NOT actual results
memo for :r0:
effect for :r0:
effect clean up for :r0:
memo for :r1:
effect for :r1:
effect clean up for :r1:
```

But to our surprise, we actually get:

```
// ACTUAL results
memo for :r0:
memo for :r1:
effect for :r1:
effect clean up :r1:
effect for :r1:
```

As you can see, the effect **never even ran** for the first iteration of the component. This is because `useEffect` is a *render* side-effect, and the first version of the component *never actually rendered*.

Also note how React's strict mode double-running operates: It runs the `useMemo` twice, once for each version of the component, but then runs the `useEffect` twice as well, both for the second component.

```
memo for :r0: // sets up Cat[0]
memo for :r1: // sets up Cat[1]
effect for :r1:
effect clean up :r1: // cleans up Cat[1] NOT Cat[0]]
effect for :r1:
```

**This is why the memo will be cleaned up right after it's set up**.

---

### TL;DR: A useMemoCleanup Hook

Ok, so because we cannot rely on effects at all (since they may *never* run for a certain version of a component), and until React provides a hook that *does* allow cleaning up a component **that never rendered**, we must rely on JS.

Fortunately, modern browsers support a feature called `FinalizationRegistry`. With a `FinalizationRegistry`, we can register a value. Then, when that value is garbage-collected by the browser, a callback will get triggered and passed a 'handled' value (in our case, the cleanup method).

Using this, and the fact that React refs and the `useRef` hook *do* follow the same lifecycle as `useMemo`, the following code can be used to allow cleanup from within a `useMemo`.

Usage: Return `[returnValue, CleanupCallback]` from your callback:

```
import { useMemo, useRef } from "react";

const registry = new FinalizationRegistry(cleanupRef => {
    cleanupRef.current && cleanupRef.current(); // cleanup on unmount
});

/** useMemoCleanup
 * A version of useMemo that allows cleanup.
 * Return a tuple from the callback: [returnValue, cleanupFunction]
 * */
export default function useMemoCleanup(callback, deps) {
    const cleanupRef = useRef(null); // holds a cleanup value
    const unmountRef = useRef(false); // the GC-triggering candidate

    if(!unmountRef.current) {
        unmountRef.current = true;
        // this works since refs are preserved for the component's lifetime
        registry.register(unmountRef, cleanupRef);
    }

    const returned = useMemo(() => {
        cleanupRef.current && cleanupRef.current();
        cleanupRef.current = null;

        const [returned, cleanup] = callback();
        cleanupRef.current = typeof cleanup === "function" ? cleanup : null;

        return returned;
    }, deps);

    return returned;
}
```

Notice: The first version of a component's cleanup method may be called *after* the initiation method of the second version of it. In React StrictMode, this occurs on mounting a component since, for testing, it runs twice. e.g.,

```
memo for :r0:
memo for :r1:
memo cleanup for :r0:
```

(Note that, due to GC behavior, it may even happen *much* later, and in no guaranteed order)

But again, if your setup and cleanup logic is pure, this shouldn't be problematic.

Comment: perfect. React has so many gotchas around `useEffect` and `useMemo` that they never actually behave as a developer expects.